# Reading txt file in js and putting those content in variable

Tags: javascript

how can i read file and put in content of that file in variable without using input file tag.

```
function loadText()
   {
     var fileToLoad = 'Dna.txt';
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
       alert(textFromFileLoaded);
   };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
 }
```

Comment: Think what would happen if browsers allowed for web sites to access random files on a user's computer.

Comment: use an `<input type=file>` and call loadText from it's onchange. you need to pass in a file object; `input.files[0]`